# Removing Bing from my Google search bar when I open a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-search, bing

Bing has rudely planted its self on my "open new tab" so above Bing my regular Google is there but below is the irritating Bing search bar! I have tried everything I know of to get rid of it and it will not go! I can not find it listed under my settings, control panel and/or uninstall!

This is the second time Bing has made its unwelcome tush comfy in my Google area! How frustrating!

I want instructions for removing Bing from my Google search bar when I open a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the annoying Bing search in Windows 8.1 by going to Tools>Manage add-ons>Search providers then deleted the Bing that was listed.  When I restarted IE Bing was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I was aghast when all my "google" searches came up on bing, and came to this very thread to find help. It was when I went to my add-ons manager that I discovered what happened. I had added the "SafeSearch Incognito" to my browser, and the only way for that to work is to use bing instead of google. So now I realize that if I want one I cannot have the other.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Control Panel called "Programs and Features" (or if you are viewing the Control Panel by Categories, click "Uninstall a program" near the bottom left). This contains a list of all software installed on your computer. Look for the Bing Toolbar, select it, and choose Uninstall from the choices at the top.

You may also have Bing installed in Chrome as an Extension. In Chrome, click the drop down menu (3 horizontal bars in the upper right) and choose Tools/Extensions to pull up a list of all your extensions. If Bing is there, you can disable it or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following information on this [web page](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sEJNzbVqLME):

If you wish to remove the Bing page and it seems not to work by changing the settings (step 2), complete all steps listed here:

1. Software
   In Windows go to Control Panel > Programs> Programs and Features. Remove all unwanted software. If you order the list by "Installed On" (newest up), the recent installed software will be at top.
2. Settings
   Paste "Chrome://settings/searchEngines" (without quotes) in your omnibox (address bar). Set the right search engine.
3. Reset Chrome settings
   Paste "Chrome://settings" (without quotes) in your omnibox (address bar) and click "Show advanced settings..." in the bottom. then scroll to the bottom again and click the reset button. Settings will be returned to default and extensions will be disabled. Enable or remove them.
4. Extensions
   Paste "Chrome://extensions" (without quotes) in your omnibox (address bar). See if strange (unwanted) extensions are listed. Disable (and Remove) them.
5. Plug-ins
   Paste "Chrome://plugins" (without quotes) in your omnibox (address bar). Disable unwanted plugins or give us a screenshot so we can tell you if something's wrong.
6. Forced installation
   Look for the extensions ID at "Chrome://extensions" by checking 'developer mode' in the right upper corner. Then open program "regedit.exe" and look in one of the following folders for the extensions ID. Remove the key with the extensions ID. It depends on your configuration which of the following folders you have in the registry.

   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Policies > Google > Chrome > ExtensionInstallForcelist
   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER > SOFTWARE > Policies > Google > Chrome > ExtensionInstallForcelist
7. Folder of extension
   If you see 'load from: ' beneath an extension at "Chrome://extensions", go to that folder and remove it.
8. Virus
   Run a virus scan with your anti-virus program. A virus may be the problem, but most times this is not the case.
9. ADWcleaner
   Remove ADWare with for example ADWcleaner. Many Chrome users get good results with it. Let the program run a scan.
10. New user profile
    If the extension is bound to a user profile, create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

[For Windows 8]

Go to Tools>Manage add-Ons> Search Providers. There you will see Bing, when you do click it and uncheck the box that says "search in the address bar and search box on the new tab page". Close out and your new tab page should be free from the Bing search box.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tool > Internet options`. In the `Generals` window look for `Tabs` and open it.

Then look for `When a new tab is opened` and change it to your first Homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for ages to find a solution and this is the only thing that worked. I found it on the Mozilla support page listed below. The solution came from a guy called "iamjayakumars"

Type about:config in the address bar

```
search for "browser.newtab.url"
value : about:newtab > double click change to "www.google.com"
```

There will be a message saying something like " this could void your warranty" just press the "I promise I'll be careful button"                                                                       Here is the Mozilla page. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/944938

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the above-mentioned change using "about:config" was not sufficient.  After I did that, I was still seeing Bing whenever I opened a new tab.

In the following folder (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\YYYYYY.default) there is a file - sessionstore.js - that contains references to Bing; I edited that file and replaced that reference with something else, like http://www.google.com).

FYI, in the file path indicated above, "xxxx" refers to your user id, and 
"YYYYYY" is a string like 47fd7upc.  Use the one you find on your machine.

Also, the "about:config" data comes from a file in that directory - "prefs.js".

Comment: UPDATE:  You can also set the value for the "browser.newtab.url" parameter to "", which will render a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I Stopped Bing from being the default search engine on Firefox 58.0.2 by;

Go to the about:config page,

Accept the warning,

Find the setting "browser.search.order1"

Change it to read -  data:text/plain,browser.search.order.1=Google

Reboot your computer - Alison

Answer (score 0):

Open the 3 dot drop down menu.On the right corner of Chrome screen.
Select settings in it.
Go to default search engines and delete bing or which ever search engine is comming up.

Answer (score 0):

"Chrometana - Redirect Bing Somewhere Better" redirects it back to Google search  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrometana-redirect-bing/kaicbfmipfpfpjmlbpejaoaflfdnabnc?hl=en

I know that's stupid, but I just gave up on removing that stupid bing redirect (charming-tab)

Answer (score 0):

Type about:config in Mozilla in ULR & then Accept the Risk and Continue
Search for browser.startup.homepage
either click on reset button at last or edit to remove url of bing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go to settings - search engine, click add next to default search engine, and paste this into the URL section. (This is for a google new tab)

{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:prefetchSource}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}

Then remove Bing, or click "Make default" for google.

Hope this helps! :)